# Does Xampp come with an FTP client?

Tags: ftp, xampp, filezilla

I'm using [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) as my solution stack. I can see it has Apache, MySQL, Filezilla, Mercury and Tomcat modules.

I need to upload some files to my web server so need an FTP client. Does Xampp come with Filezilla the FTP Client? or is it just FTP Server? Or perhaps it's both?

Hoping someone can explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Xampp only comes with the FTP Server. You would need to download the client separately as it's a separate app. Xampp is a collection of web services, and a FTP client doesn't come under that umbrella.

[Here is the doco.](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/FAQ)

---

Xampp comes with Filezilla server, it's an optional install with the main installer.

[Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x8xEZq43wgc)

Comment: The video talks about Filezilla FTP Server

Comment: Xampp installs Filezilla. Xampp is just an outer shell of other web technologies (PHP, Apache, Filezilla etc), it provides the multi installer, and a system tray app to manage all the services in one.

Comment: Filezilla Client and Filezilla Server are separate. My question is: does Xampp come with the FTP *client*? I already know it comes with the FTP server.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Misread your question. It only installs the FTP server. You can easily download the client separately though. I will update above.

Comment: I thought the same about just the server. I didn't want to go ahead and install the client just in case it was already installed and any conflicts came up etc

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please mark as correct. I need the rep to do something on another question:)